# error: React is not defined, when i try deploying to github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQgMd.png)

i get this error, can someone help me?

ive used the install gh-pages, and it publiches but dosnt work

Comment: Can you upload your code as well?

Comment: https://github.com/thereseml/portfolio

Comment: You need to make it public first.